# How to setup and run StageMonitor tool (https://github.com/stagemonitor/stagemonitor)?

Tags: performance, installation, monitor, stagemonitor

I am new to Stagemonitor, and I found that it is one of the best open source tool to get the performace metrics. So, I tried to implement this for my tomcat server. But I cannot get a clear documentation to implement and setup this.

The wiki provided in the github page is not enough to setup the application.

Can anyone guide me how to install this tool and make it a go.!!

Comment: What's missing in the documentation? At which step did you get stuck?